# Help Identify the name of the Hessen-Cassel Grenadier Company 1786

Tags: german-to-english, handwriting

Von der ?ügell Grenadier Compagnie

Drittes Regiment Garde[image] 1786

Answer (score 5):

It is definitely "Flügel Grenadier Compagnie". The second "l" is a spelling mistake.

Some interesting links are

- [Militairy and phaleristic history of the Kurfürstentum Hessen](https://kurhessen.owlstown.net/), especially  [Flügel-Grenadier-Compagnien](https://kurhessen.owlstown.net/pages/2-2-1-2-garde-grenadier-regiment)
- [Flügel-Grenadier](https://www.deutsche-digitale-bibliothek.de/item/JEXTGSDESSIMH2YFJPQDAPTNXZMMOQGL)
- [Hessisches Staatsarchiv Darmstadt](https://arcinsys.hessen.de/arcinsys/list.action?nodeid=g25015&page=1)

**Update:**

The first line is

> Maass und Rangier Rolle

See [here](https://arcinsys.hessen.de/arcinsys/detailAction.action?detailid=v2788221).

Comment: Was German spelling sufficiently standardised in 1786 for this to be considered a spelling mistake rather than a variant spelling?

Comment: @JackAidley Certainly it was not as much standardised as today, but there is no indication that the spelling "Flügell" would have been in use about the year 1800. See [here](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/fl%C3%BCgel) for examples taken from German literature.

Answer (score 3):

I would say the incomplete word means

> Flügel

See [Wikipedia](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibgarde-Regiment_(Hessen-Kassel)), but I can't recognize the reason for the second L.